# Filtering two lists f#

Tags: list, recursion, filter, f#

I have two string lists, one with humanIds that fulfill some conditions (humanosPosibles), and another list that contain humanIds that may or may not fulfill the conditions (likesTodo).The thing is, I need to create one list that contains only the humansIds that are in likesTodo and also in humanosPosibles.  I tried doing it with recursion and a list.filter. I'll put my code for you to see what is it that I am doing wrong.  If you think this is not the best way to do it, please make suggestions.

```
  let rec pasa (likesTodo:string list) (humanosPosibles:string list) x y =
        if (y < humanosPosibles.Length) then
            if (likesTodo.[x] = humanosPosibles.[y]) then
                true 
            else
                pasa likesTodo humanosPosibles x (y+1)  
        else
            false  

 let genteFiltrada = List.filter (fun x -> pasa likesTodo humanosPosibles 0 0 ) likesTodo
```

genteFiltrada corresponds to the list that I need to create. The last time I forgot to say that if one item of likesTodo is duplicated I need it to be two times in the new list. Therefore, set won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using set, as what you want is the intersection:

```
let intersectlists a b = 
    let la,lb = Set.ofList a, Set.ofList b
    Set.intersect la lb |> Set.toList
```

Comment: Could be little bit shorter:<br/> `let intersectlists a b = 
    (Set.ofList a, Set.ofList b) 
    ||> Set.intersect 
    |> Set.toList`

Comment: i have a question, if one of the items in the list likesTodo is repeated several times, and it is also find in the list humanosPosibles, it will be added one time, or several times to the new list?

Comment: @Tomas - The way that `set` works, it will remove duplicates for you.

Comment: @JohnPalmer what if i need the duplicates to be there! haha